# ASP.net UpdatePanel dynamically using C# code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a custom usercontrol that has some Asp.net code. I would like to write the same code but with C#.
The problem is that i don't know how to put a repeater and some buttons into the ContentTemplate.

The Asp.net Code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up">

    <ContentTemplate>

        <n2:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
        </n2:Repeater>

         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnFirst" 
           Visible="false" Enabled="false" Text="<<" OnClick="btnFirst_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So how could I write this chunk in C# code? To be precise, how could I insert the repeater and the Linkbutton into the ContentTemplate.

Note : I don't want to use the LoadTemplate to do it.

**Edit**

I have tried ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add():

```
    private UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
    private Repeater rpt = Repeater();;

    public Paging{      

    //Add repeater to updatePanel
    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(rpt);


     AsyncPostBackTrigger apb3 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
     apb3.ControlID = "btnFirst";
     apb3.EventName = "Click";

     //Add Triggers to updatePanel
     up.Triggers.Add(apb1);

      //Create buttons
      btnFirst = new LinkButton();
      btnFirst.Visible = false;
      btnFirst.Enabled = false;
      btnFirst.Text = "<<";
      btnFirst.Click += new EventHandler(btnFirst_Click);

     //Add buttons to update panel
       up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(btnFirst);

     }

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        rpt.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/UI/Templates/NewsEvent.ascx");
       ....
     }
```

I have an error caused by the first line on Page_Load :
*Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in controls contained in a page.*

This is NewsEvent.ascx:

```
<img src='<%# Eval("ImageThumbnail") %>' alt="" />
```

Comment: What exactly you need? What have you tried?

Comment: @VMAtm, please see the Edit question's part.

Comment: NewsEvent.ascx this controls have some error, you used Eval or bind method in the control which is used database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do this with ITemplate types ... i had a similar problem trying to clone a tabpanel in a tabcontainer control ... i already had a hidden tabpanel and all i wanted to do was create a new tabpanel and basically instantiate the ITemplate from the hidden one in the new one.

The problem is ITemplate ... it's not very dynamic for code behind interactions i would suggest putting that markup on the page as you already have and setting visible = false on the parent then when you need to databind and show the hidden panel.

getting the initial bind to work isn't the problem ... its the postback handling ...

[Ajax TabContainerTabPanels Break postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953006/ajax-tabcontainertabpanels-break-postbacks)